# Is it true that every vector bundle over a non compact smooth manifold is trivial at infinity?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a non compact smooth manifold and suppose that $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ is a vector bundle over it. Is there a compact subset $K\subset M$ such that the restricted bundle $\pi|_U:E|_U\rightarrow U$ over $U:=M-K$ becomes trivial? In other words, is it true that every vector bundle over a non compact manifold can be extended to a (continuous) vector bundle over its one point compactification $M^+:=M\cup\{\infty\}$?

Comment: That fails already for rank $1$ vector bundles over $M = \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{S}^1$.  For the tautological rank $1$ vector bundle $F$ on $\mathbb{S}^1=\mathbb{RP}^1$, the pullback $E=\text{pr}_2^*F$ gives a counterexample.  For every compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{S}^1$, the image $\text{pr}_1(K)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, hence bounded.  Thus, there exists $t\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \text{pr}_1(K)$.  For the section $\sigma_t:\mathbb{S}^1\to M$ by $\sigma_t(u)=(t,u)$, the pullback $\sigma_t^*E$ equals $F$.

Comment: That's right, Jason Starr.

Comment: @JasonStarr Could you make an answer from you comment? (to move it from unanswered questions).

Answer (score 5):

As requested by user @AntonPetrunin, I am turning my comment into an answer.

That fails already for rank $1$ vector bundles over $M=\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{S}^1$.  For the tautological rank $1$ vector bundle $F$ on $\mathbb{S}^1=\mathbb{RP}^1$, the pullback $E=\text{pr}_2^*F$ gives a counterexample.  For every compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{S}^1$, the image $\text{pr}_1(K)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, hence bounded.  Thus, there exists $t\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \text{pr}_1(K)$.  For the section $\sigma_t:\mathbb{S}^1\to M$ by $\sigma_t(u)=(t,u)$, the pullback $\sigma_t^*E$ equals $F$.